# compare 2 directories and show diff to each files

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have this folder I cloned through a git project. But after running some trouble, and ignoring some stuffed my files (DIR 1) it stopped working (in a sense, the files are C++ codes, cannot compile it anymore)

Finally, I decided to download a new working Git clone (DIR 2). But i still wish all the file changes in my DIR 1 can be used to DIR 2 which I wish I can apply manually to know where did I go wrong.

I am currently resorting to online quick diff checker to compare each file one by one. But this is taking too much time for a multi directory and 40,000+ files. Since not all files were modified.

Hope there's a program that can just tell me the files in DIR 1 that is different from the files of DIR 2 and tell me what are the lines different.

Thanks!

Comment: beyond compare and kdiff do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-clone the project into DIR 2. From DIR 1, execute the following command

```
$ git diff
```

You'll see the differences between your changes and the original code. If you have changed many files and just want to see the differences of one file. Execute the following

```
$ git diff path/to/file
```